# SpringBoot 2 with Flyway: spring.flyway.locations is ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.2 with Flyway 5.2.4 and I tried to configure flyway to use a differente location for the scripts, but `spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:db_other/migration/{vendor}` neither `flyway.locations=filesystem:db_other/migration/{vendor}` configurations on application.properties worked.

When running the program, the following exception appear in the log:
`FlywayMigrationScriptMissingException: Cannot find migration scripts in: [classpath:db/migration]`

I already tried using Spring Boot 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.11 and Flyway 6.1.0 and 6.1.3, but the result is the same.

Comment: Where is `db_other` in relation to the project files?

Comment: In the resources folder (src/main/resources/db_other/migration/postgres)

Comment: Okay, since the contents of the resources folder will wind up on the classpath, you can reference it as such. Have you tried replacing "filesystem" with "classpath" in your property value?

Comment: How are you running your application ? Could please show us the pom.xml ? I've tried locally, it is working fine for me. mvn spring-boot:run is failing, but my custom spring.flyway.locations is used (located inside src/main/resources/application.properties)

Comment: In fact I was trying to run a Junit 5 test that need flyway to execute and the problema just happens in the test; running the application normally it works. I created a issue on flyway for that https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2614

Comment: What is your maven/gradle configuration for the flyway?

Comment: I do not use maven/gradle with Flyway... it is executed by the application itself (by the SpringBoot in the case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if was my fault: as I used to work with just spring (not spring boot) I configured my test class with the annotations @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) AND @ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfiguration.class }) instead of just use @SpringBootTest. When making this change the test worked.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for that property is classpath:db/migration as shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) (search for flyway).

Since you're using a different folder in the resources directory you should only need to change "filesystem" to "classpath" in your application.properties value.